# How to disable L1/L2 cache on arm64?

Tags: caching, linux-kernel, arm64

I want to know how to disable the L1/L2 cache on arm64 with linux kernel version >= 5.10.

I found the way of insmod `.ko` file (changed bit of sctlr_el1), but it doesn't work.
And I also found a config `CONFIG_CPU_DCACHE_DISABLE`, but it seem only used for arm.

My question is:

1. Where the code path to enable L1/L2 cache on arm64 in linux kernel now?
2. How to disable L1/L2 cache? Any configs? or Change the code? or Insmod `.ko`?
   Please help to supply the related code.

Comment: slightly ping..